# Shopping Cart not loading while there are 1000 items in cart ( Magento 1 Enterprise )

Tags: cart, magento-enterprise, shopping-cart, magento-1.14

- My Shopping Cart is  not loading while i put 1000 different items in cart .
- I know it seems odd but we have customers that do that , its a wholesale website . I did change the value of the default magento from 1000 to 10000 https://d.pr/free/i/Pr4uO1 , but still the same issue.
- I did the flush of cache, full reindex. Didn`t got any luck on loading the shopping cart. Wonder what is causing the issue and if it is anything else i can update. Is any other way to debug the issue instead of adding 1000 different item in cart ?

Answer (score 0):

This article provides best practices for the number of products in a cart in Adobe Commerce. The maximum recommended number of products is 100.

The potential site impact of exceeding the limit is:

An increase in data retrieval operations, validation of cart items, checks for price rules applications, tax calculations, and totals calculations.
An increase in the time for mini-cart rendering including cart rendering time, checkout flow rendering, and execution, leading to performance degradation.
Increase in the page loading time for all site pages where the mini-cart is present, leading to performance degradation.
Adobe Commerce Best Practices for cart limits are:

Up to 100 products in a cart
the product works, meeting performance targets for response time.
Up to 300 products in a cart
the product works, but response time increases above targets.
Above 500 products in a cart
the cart and checkout flows are not guaranteed to work.